# Limit points of a set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If $A=\{\frac{2}{m}+\frac{3}{n}:m,n\in \mathbb N\}$, then what is the derived set of $A$ in $\mathbb R$?

Definitely $0$ is a limit point of $A$. I think for all $n\in \mathbb N$, all numbers of the form $\frac{2}{n}, \frac{3}{n}$ are also limit points. Thus the derived set of $A$ will be $\{\frac{2}{n}:n\in \mathbb N\}\cup \{\frac{3}{n}:n\in \mathbb N\}\cup \{0\}$. Am I right?

Comment: yes you're correct!

Comment: But you should also prove that there is no other limit point ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think {1/k:k is in N} also counts. Let m=2k, the sum can be arbitrarily close to 1/k as m goes to infinity. Am I right?